# Validating RESTful URLs for every request the DRY way

Tags: validation, rest, grails

Our Grails 2.4.4 application is using RESTful URLs throughout. Given the following URL:

/stores/123/products/456

I'd like to validate that there is a store with an ID of 123, and if not, redirect to a 404 on every request to the Product controller. I don't want to have to put that store lookup code in each action method, nor do I want to create a controller base class, because then I have to put a method call in every action method.

Can this be done with a interceptor somehow?

Comment: In Grails 2.4.4, filters can be used to intercept the request to `ProductController`. `params.storeId=123` and `params.id=456`. `Store.exists()` would check if store with strore id 123 exists. If not, redirect to 404 page, return false. From Grails 3.0, filter is deprecated, and similar implementation can be done using [Interceptors](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#interceptors).

Comment: Thanks. I looked at interceptors a bit and the before() triggers after the action method but right before view rendering, which is too late. Am I missing something?

Comment: Interceptors are introduced in Grails 3.0. You would need [filters](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/single.html#filters) in Grails 2.4.4. `before = { }` is what will be needed here. Also look at the docs which variable are available to filters by default (eg: params, request, response etc). If this is still unclear, I can add an answer as an example. But I hope docs will be self explanatory.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Please move your last comment as an answer and I will accept that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interceptors are introduced in Grails 3.0. You would need [filters](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/single.html#filters) in Grails 2.4.4.

`before = { }` is what will be needed here.

Also look at the docs which variable are available to filters by default (eg: params, request, response etc). If this is still unclear, I can add an answer as an example. But I hope docs will be self explanatory. As an example i would do it as

```
class EntityCheckFilters {
    def filters = {
        storeExistCheck( controller:'product' ) {
            before = {
               if ( !params.storeId || !Store.exists( params.sotreId as Long ) ) {
                    response.sendError(404)
                    // or for example if you have a separate action to handle 404
                    // redirect(action: 'handle404')

                    // this is important, 
                    // because we do not want to pass through with the original call
                    return false 
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using:

1. **URL Mapping**
2. **Filters**

But I dont think putting a logic (checking if there is a valid store with the given id) in URL Mapping is good idea, so better to use Filters.

So you url mapping will look like this:

```
"/stores/$storeId/products/$productId" (controller = "product")
```

And your filter:

```
class YourFilterNameFilters {


    def filters = {
        secureReports(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {

               if(parmas.controller == "product" && params.storeId){
                     Store store = Store.get(params.sotreId)
                    if(!store){
                        response.sendError(404)
                     }
                 }
           }
      }
}
```